# How to parse xml data received as response text from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a webservice call. which send the response in the encrypted format as reponse text. when I decrypt the response text I will get an XML data. Now I want to parse this xml data. Can any one please give some idea

```
var respon = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

alert(respon);

var xml = jQuery(respon);
alert(xml.find('line:first').text());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your response xml inside `$` function. Like lets say you got :

```
var str = '<NewDataSet> <Table> <line>1</line> <Trimestre>Octubre-Diciembre</Trimestre> <currency>EU?</currency> <growth>6.7</growth> <balanced>4.73</balanced> <moderate>2.98</moderate> </Table> <Table> <line>1</line> <Trimestre>Octubre-Diciembre</Trimestre> <currency>US$</currency> <growth>10.76</growth> <balanced>7.57</balanced> <moderate>5.44</moderate> </Table> </NewDataSet> ';

var xml = jQuery(str);
console.log(xml.find('line:first').text())
```

Use debugger or console.log to further iterate your `$(xml)`

Comment: I am getting response as responseText not as responseXml

Comment: Yeah, whatever you get, you have to enclose that xml string into `$` function. Use `$(responseText)` to start parsing. For reference, you can use this link: http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/

Comment: <NewDataSet>
 <Table>
 <line>1</line> 
 <Trimestre>Octubre-Diciembre</Trimestre>  
 <currency>EU?</currency>  
 <growth>6.7</growth>    
 <balanced>4.73</balanced>  
 <moderate>2.98</moderate>  
 </Table>   
 <Table>    
 <line>1</line>    
 <Trimestre>Octubre-Diciembre</Trimestre>  
 <currency>US$</currency>  
 <growth>10.76</growth>    
 <balanced>7.57</balanced>  
 <moderate>5.44</moderate>   
 </Table>
 </NewDataSet>              This is the xml am getting from responseText . when I decrypt the responsetext

Comment: See the updated answer. I have just wrote one way so that you can access `line` nodes and have printed its inner text.

Comment: It IS working. I have first tested it on my side, then only have updated the answer. What error are you getting on your side?

Comment: Am running it in IE. I just kept an alert . am not gettin that alert

Comment: You should show all your relevant code here... Only then can some one help. By the way in your case browser really doesn't matter. If it's not working on IE, it wont work on other browsers too.

Comment: How to read 2nd table values. "second" or "Second" is not working

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what 'parse' means exactly. But if 'parse' means fetch several data from some xml, the code below would help.

```
var data = [];

$.ajax({
    url: "some-url/sample.xml",
        async: true,
        cache: true,
        dataType:"xml",
        success: function(xml){
            $(xml).find('item').each(function(i){
                data.push({
                    'id': $(this).find("id").text(),
                    'title'    : $(this).find("title").text()
                });
            });
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

sample.xml

```
<item>
<id>1</id>
<title>Alasteir</title>
</item>
<item>
<id>2</id>
<title>Bob</title>
</item>
<item>
<id>3</id>
<title>John</title>
</item>
<item>
<id>4</id>
<title>Mary</title>
</item>
<item>
<id>5</id>
<title>Tom</title>
</item>
```